# Smoke Testing and Monkey Testing in ABAP

Tags: abap, smoke-testing, monkey-testing

How can i do smoke and monkey testing in ABAP? Are there tools for that ?

Answer (score 1):

Smoke testing can be automatized by using [eCATT](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw04/helpdata/en/1b/e81c3b84e65e7be10000000a11402f/content.htm). Note that the creation of eCATT tests is quite time-consuming, so you should do a cost-benefit analysis beforehand.

I don't know of any tools for monkey testing, except maybe creating a ABAP Unit test suit which uses randomly generated data.